# Notepad++: Syntax Highlighting Before Saving a File

Tags: syntax, notepad++, highlighting

After doing some Google Searching, and taking a look through StackOverflow, I can't seem to figure out something.

Is it possible to have syntax highlighting in Notepad++ as soon as you open a new file? I know it'll show up once you save the file, based on the saved file type, and it's also possible to change the default save type. (from .txt to .py or .java)

The functionality I'm looking for is the same type you'd get from something like Eclipse for Java, or Visual C++. Basically most IDE's.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can select the language to be highlighted as from the menu.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I think the OP wants to select a default language at Notepad++ startup for the purposes of syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

When you start up Notepad++, go to:

1. **Settings** [menu bar]
2. **Preferences...**
3. **New Document/Default Directory** [tab]
4. **Default language** [combo box]
5. Pick your favorite language.

[image: Notepad++ Preferences Dialog Box]

Answer (score 2):

In *Settings* > *Preferences*, go to the **New Document/Default Directory** tab, and change the Default Language to your preference (C#, etc.). That should let you type in keywords, and get them automatically highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys. I had already tried that, but now it seems to work. I think I missed it because for some reason its only bolding them in black. (I seem to remember other colors.)

Comment: Annoyingly, it doesn't let you pick user defined languages and Markdown isn't in the official list for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

In the 10 Jan 2015 build version,
You can go to:

- **Languages** in the Menu Bar,

   and select your language from there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @adam-karlson is the best way to do it.
Adding more to this, you could also disable the unwanted languages in the ['Language perferences settings'](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#language) and make the language tab more compact.

[Image : Perferences > Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUlMc.png)

You can also find the User defined languages in the list.